# Flex MXML Layout Issue

Tags: apache-flex, layout, mobile, mxml

So what I want is the ToggleSwitch on the left and a Button on the right. When the Screen is too small, I want the Button to get smaller and show some "...". So I used:

```
<s:Group width="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:ToggleSwitch />
    <s:Spacer width="100%"/>
    <s:Button label="TestTestTestTestTest"/>
</s:Group>
```

This works fine, until the Screen is so small that the entire label text from the button doens't fit. Then both components are floating left and right outside of the screen.

So I tried it by using a basic layout:

```
<s:Group width="100%">
    <s:ToggleSwitch left="0" />
    <s:Button right="0" label="TestTestTestTestTest"/>
</s:Group>
```

Doens't work either. When screen is too small the button is floating over the toggleswitch.
So how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably almost there, for one if you want side by side, just start with an HGroup and to protect against layout "border violations" of it's parent, turn on the clipAndEnableScrolling property.

```
<s:HGroup width="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
    <s:ToggleSwitch />
    <s:Rect width="100%" />
    <s:Button label="TestTestTestTestTest"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the job. Didn't know about this property.. :)

Comment: Hmm any idea how I can make the button show "..." when truncated?

Comment: truncation is handled for you on text-based components but apparently not in others like Buttons - I don't remember if this was done for Halo. It gets a little more involved, but you actually can do this with a SkinComponent. If you sub-class the ButtonSkin, starting from here you can write a simple algorithm which is right-looking at how much room is left vs. the total width of the label display, then substr / substring at least 3 more characters and insert the ellipsis.